# How to snap the page dimensions to the grid in ConTeXt?

Tags: margins, context, book-design, context-mkiv, grid-typesetting

In ConTeXt, I am using the setting `grid=yes` to make all of the text in a document use grid typesetting. ConTeXt seems to automatically adjust the height of this grid based on the size of the font selected.

I found that these grid dimensions do not match the vertical height of the page, so the grid overflows and some lines are not of full height. I would like to adjust the page dimensions so that it matches the grid. I will assume that the designers of this system used a good algorithm for deciding which grid size should be used, so I will not attempt to adjust that measurement.

- How can I obtain the value of the vertical distance of the grid?
- Is there any way to set the vertical and horizontal dimensions of the text area on a page to snap to the grid?

Comment: Please add a MWE

Comment: What I do is set the height of the text area to the desired multiple of the interlineskip. What do you mean with „vertical distance of the grid“ -- the distance of an element to the next grid level? Also I’m not sure there’s any horizontal grid snapping going on. Can you be a bit more precise on that?

Comment: No MWE, so answering is not possible => too localized. Ask for reopening if a MWE is available.